# is there any ways to get specific column from csv file?

Tags: c++, csv, getline

[image]

Hi all, im just start to learn how to do the csv file management using c++, currently this code works. it can print out the 'math' column.

but that is only if when i assigned every column using the getline(ss,#any column variable#, ',')
then i print out the column that i want. but if im using this for a big list, lets say a csv file that have about 100 column. then, how can i simplified it? or is there any ways for me to only get specific column only without assigning/parsing each column to each variable? lets say from 100 column, i only want the column 47 with any possible names? or maybe i could get the column by its name?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't show images of text, least of all code. Copy-paste the text *as text* into the question instead.

Comment: Anything is possible if you write code for it. Read each line into a `std::vector<std::string>`, then you can index on it. If you then also read the first line into a `std::map<std::string, int>` you could grab columns by name.

Comment: As for your problem, I recommend that you study *structures* and *classes*, and the standard containers (like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)). And remember that you can have a vector inside a structure (for e.g. data fields).

Comment: Yes, vector of strings is your best bet. Then you can just choose the element with index 46. If you attach the csv i can take a look at it

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude alright sir. next time i will do it properly. thank you for your advice and sorry for my mistakes. Hehe

Comment: alright guys. im going to read about vector now. thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick [working] example.

- The 1st part reads in the table.
- The 2nd part (after `fin.close()`) lets you choose what you want to print out (or whatever you choose to do with it).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>  //std::find
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   ifstream fin("filename");
   string line;
   int rowCount=0;
   int rowIdx=0; //keep track of inserted rows

   //count the total nb of lines in your file
   while(getline(fin,line)){
      rowCount++;
   }

   //this will be your table. A row is represented by data[row_number].
   //If you want to access the name of the column #47, you would
   //cout << data[0][46]. 0 being the first row(assuming headers)
   //and 46 is the 47 column.
   //But first you have to input the data. See below.
   vector<string> data[rowCount];

   fin.clear(); //remove failbit (ie: continue using fin.)
   fin.seekg(fin.beg); //rewind stream to start

   while(getline(fin,line)) //for every line in input file
   {
      stringstream ss(line);  //copy line to stringstream
      string value;
      while(getline(ss,value,’,’)){       //for every value in that stream (ie: every cell on that row)
         data[rowIdx].push_back(value);//add that value at the end of the current row in our table
      }
      rowIdx++;   //increment row number before reading in next line
   }
}
   fin.close();


   //Now you can choose to access the data however you like.
   //If you want to printout only column 47...

   int colNum=47;  //set this number to the column you want to printout

   for(int row=0; row<rowCount; row++)
   {
      cout << data[row][colNum] << "\t";  //print every value in column 47 only
   }
   cout << endl


   return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Adding this for a more complete answer.

To search a column by name, replace the last for loop with this snippet

```
   //if you want to look up a column by name, instead of by column number...
   //Use find on that row to get its column number.
   //Than you can printout just that column.
   int colNum;
   string colName = "computer science";

   //1.Find the index of column name "computer science" on the first row, using iterator
   //note: if "it == data[0].end()", it means that that column name was not found 
   vector<string>::iterator it = find(data[0].begin(), data[0].end(),colName);  

   //calulate its index (ie: column number integer)  
   colNum = std::distance(data[0].begin(), it);   

   //2. Print the column with the header "computer science"
   for(int row=0; row<rowCount; row++)
   {
      cout << data[row][colNum] << "\t";  //print every value in column 47 only
   }
   cout << endl

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, this example and your explanation is very helpful. this one could do what i want, now im trying to study the other solution given by others also. hehe.

Comment: That's great! Glad I can help. Check out my edit too, I added some code to look column by name specifically.

Comment: sorry. for that searching from column name didnt work, it gave me no matching function for call to find vector.....

Comment: oops add this in your includes `#include <algorithm>`
Sorry about that

Comment: Let me know if you have any other issue with this

Comment: ya, can you help me with this one? it is integrated from this question. but almost the same, it is just that i used different IDE. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349006/this-code-gives-me-errors-when-compiled-using-visual-studio-2012-but-with-codeb

Comment: hi @calvinBroadus this one works just fine but i found something, if the column that i am searching for is the last column, so it could get that column, since the last column in csv dont have the comma(,). how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> or is there any ways for me to only get specific column only without assigning/parsing each column to each variable?

It's not really practical with the CSV format to avoid *reading* every column, so really what you want to do is basically just *discard* the columns you do not want, much like you are already doing.

To make it work with an unknown number of columns, you can read into a `std::vector`, which is basically a dynamically sized array, so really useful for cases like this.

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> read_csv_line(const std::string &line)
{
    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    std::string val;
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    while (std::getline(ss, val, ','))
        ret.push_back(std::move(val));
    return ret;
}

...
std::getline(is, line);
auto row = read_csv_line(line);
if (row.size() > 10) // Check each row is expected size!
  std::cout << row[0] << ", " << row[10] << std::endl;
else std::cerr << "Row too short" << std::endl;
```

You can then access the specific columns you want.

> or maybe i could get the column by its name?

Assuming your CSV file has a header line, you can read that into say a `std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t>` where the value is the column index. Alternatively something like a `std::vector` with `std::find`.

---

Note that handling of quoted values, and some other possible CSV features can't be done with a single `std::getline`.