# This code gives me errors when compiled using visual studio 2012, but with codeblocks it is okay

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, constants, codeblocks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

#define ADDR "c:\\Users\\Library2\\Desktop\\Books record\\"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   ifstream fin(ADDR "reportcard.csv", ios::binary);
   string line;
   int rowCount=0;
   int rowIdx=0; 

   while(getline(fin,line)){
       rowCount++;
   }

   vector<string> data[**rowCount**];//this rowCount gave me "expression must have a constant value"

   fin.clear(); 
   fin.seekg(fin.beg); 

   while(getline(fin,line)) 
   {
      stringstream ss(line);  
      string value;
      while(getline(ss,value,',')){       
         data[rowIdx].push_back(value);
      }
      rowIdx++;   
   }

   fin.close();

   int colNum;
   string colName = "LAST PERSON";
   static int it;

   for(vector<string>::iterator it = data[0].begin(); it != data[0].end(); ++it)
   {
       if ((*it)== colName)
       {
           colNum = distance(data[0].begin(),it);//distance() gave me "no instances of function templates matches argument"
           break;
       }
   }
   cout << data[1][colNum] << "\t";

   return 0;
}
```

1. im trying to figure out why it gave me the expression must have a constant value.
2. im trying to find another function that works the same as distance() that can be used in visual studio 2012.

note: this code is for finding and getting the value from the first cell under a column called "LAST PERSON". This code is already okay when using codeblocks. but i need to use visual studio.

Comment: What errors does it give to you?

Comment: i did put the error message that visual studio gave me as a comment on that line. the error was for line;
vector<string> data[**rowCount**];//this rowCount gave me "expression must have a constant value"

then, 

colNum = distance(data[0].begin(),it);//distance() gave me "no instances of function templates matches argument"

Comment: u can refer back to the code, hehe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: wait. let me read and check that one out. btw, thanks for ur feedback guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
vector<string> data[rowCount];
```

is a declaration of a variable length array.

Variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature. Some compilers have their own language extensions that allow to use variable length arrays. Other compilers do not have such a language extension.

Instead of the array you could use a vector of vectors as for example

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data;
```

Pay attention to that as the file is opened in the binaru mode

```
ifstream fin(ADDR "reportcard.csv", ios::binary);
```

then using the function `std::getline` is not correct in general case.

```
while(getline(fin,line)){
    rowCount++;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data(rowCount);` looks like it would be the correct declaration, given the rest of the code.

Comment: thank you both of you. actually i havent fully understand yet what does vector<vector<string>> is. but i just tried and applied it. and yes. both of the errors gone. thank you so much guys. now i need to read something about this to understand it. i will start to google about it.

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler sees this:

```
vector<string> data[rowCount];
```

it starts from `data` and looks to the right. It sees '[' and interprets `data` to be a C-style array. Then it sees `rowCount` and checks if it is a compile-time constant. If not, this code is against the standard. Still, some compilers allow this as a language extension.

All in all, you've defined a C-style array of `rowCount` elements of type `vector<string>`. You must have mistaken [] for () or {}. Most likely you wanted to write

```
std::vector<std::string> data(rowCount); // a vector of rowCount strings
```